# How do I package for distribution a python module that uses a shared library?

Tags: python, ctypes, setuptools, distutils

I'm writing some bindings for a C library and am not sure how to configure all this for distribution so it is possible to `pip install` my package.

Let's say I have the following files:

- `library.c`
- `library.h`
- `wrapper.py`

In order for my wrapper library to work it is necessary to:

- compile library.c and create a shared library
- run `ctypesgen` on `library.h` to generate the ctypes code

Here are the commands:

- `gcc -Wall -fPIC -c library.c`
- `gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,liblibrary.so.1 -o liblibrary.so.1.0 library.o`
- `ctypesgen.py library.h -L ./ -l library -o _library.py`

Running `setup.py` will also depend on the user having installed `ctypesgen`.

I have no idea how to get this all set up so that someone interested in the library can simply `pip install library` and have all this happen automagically. Anyone able to help?

Comment: You could put an `import` of the required dependency in a `try/except` at the top of the setup script, and put the code to pip install the dependency in the `except` block

Comment: No I think you need to put it in `install_requires` or a similar directive.

Comment: Yeah, that would be more correct, I'm not sure how either tho. Side note, I recognize your SO username from your blog, I liked your post on markov chaining, used it as a basis for my own markov chaining irc bot :)

Comment: note that the requirement is a C library - it's "distribution" (library.so + library.h) is not a Python package and would not naturally be listed on PyPI (so dependencies would not work).

Answer (score 9):

The Extensions capability of setuptools/distutils is what you need.

[Documentation has more information](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/building.html), in short an example setup.py to do the above would look like the below

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages, Extension

extensions = [Extension("my_package.ext_library",
                       ["src/library.c"],
                       depends=["src/library.h"],
                       include_dirs=["src"],
              ),
]
setup(<..>,
     ext_modules=extensions,
)
```

The `.so` is generated automatically by `setup.py` when the module is built. If it needs to link to other libraries can supply a `libraries` argument list to the extension. See docs([1](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/building.html)) for more info.

Since this is built in functionality of setuptools, it works fine with `pip` and can be distributed (as source code only) on pypi. All source files referenced by the `Extension` must be present in the distributed pypi archive.

If you want to build distributable *binary* wheels including native code [see manylinux](https://github.com/pypa/python-manylinux-demo).

Comment: This code is working perfectly for me but the name of the library seems to change depending on the system. For my system, the library is named `ext_library.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`. How can I predict the name of the package to import it in my python script ?

Comment: You do not need to. The file name is auto-generated depending on interpreter version and architecture. Only the name used when setting up extension is used on import, eg `import my_package.ext_library` from the above.

Comment: To add header files to the tar.gz source package, a MANIFEST.in file is required. `python3 -m build` uses `sdist` to generate the tar.gz and it won’t include header files by default. The `setup.cfg` and `setup.py` files won’t help.