# What's the difference between setup.py and setup.cfg in python projects

Tags: python, python-2.7, openstack, setuptools

Need to know what's the difference between setup.py and setup.cfg. Both are used prominently in openstack projects

Comment: Also see [PEP-621](https://peps.python.org/pep-0621/) for `pyproject.toml`.

Comment: and a useful comparison in `setuptools` [documentation](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/dependency_management.html)

Answer (score 95):

tldr:

- `setup.py` can contain contain any Python code. Complex and bad.
- `setup.cfg` only declares things. Simple and good.
- Same advantages, more modern: [`pyproject.toml`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/build-system/pyproject-toml/)

---

Traditionally, `setup.py` has been used to build a Python package, i.e.,

```
python setup.py build
```

Like any old Python file, `setup.py` can contain lots of code. In most cases, however, it is purely declarative and simply lists package properties, e.g.,

```py
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name="foobar",
    version="0.1.0",
    author="John Doe",
    # ...
)
```

In fact, some consider it *bad style* to put much logic in `setup.py`. To reflect that, `setup.cfg` (which is declarative by design) has become more popular for packaging:

```
[metadata]
name = foobar
version = 0.1.0
author = John Doe
# ...
```

This has the advantage that the packaging software (e.g., setuptools) doesn't need to *evaluate* a Python file to get the meta data, but can simply *parse* a config file.

You can add a dummy `setup.py` to that,

```py
from setuptools import setup

if __name__ == "__main__":
    setup()
```

or go full [PEP 517](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0517/)/[518](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0518/) and instead add a `pyproject.toml`.

```ini
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools>=42", "wheel"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"
```

You can then build your projects using [pypa-build](https://github.com/pypa/build) (`pip install build`) with

```
python3 -m build --sdist --wheel .
```

[Since 2020 `pyproject.toml` can contain metadata too](https://peps.python.org/pep-0621/#example), so you don't need `setup.cfg` anymore. The data layout looks more or less like `setup.cfg` but follows the standardized [TOML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TOML) format:

```ini
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools>=61"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[project]
name = "foobar"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = [{name = "John Doe", email = "john@doe.com"}]
# [...]
```

One design goal is that multiple build systems will support it ([setuptools](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/1688), [flit](https://github.com/pypa/flit/issues/377), [Poetry](https://github.com/python-poetry/roadmap/issues/3), ...).

Comment: Package without `setup.py` ? `pip install --editable .` can raise "ERROR: File "setup.py" not found ... (A "pyproject.toml" file was found, but editable mode currently requires a setup.py based build.)" for example on `meshplex`.

Comment: @denis You'll probably need `-m pep517.build`. (See the Makefile in meshplex.)

Comment: [This stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42932451/75517) explain how to create a package with a c library extension. It provides an example with code added to setup.py. Can the equivalent be done with `setup.cfg` ? If yes, could you please give an example ?

Comment: @chmike For C extensions, you'll still have to keep a `setup.py` around. The meta data can go into `setup.cfg`, though. Check out https://github.com/nschloe/pygalmesh/blob/main/setup.py as an example.

Comment: I suppose this is a good answer but honestly it mostly made me more confused about what files I'm supposed to create in a new package.

Comment: "has become more popular for packaging" pretty suspicious there. I think it's more... what you are meant to do.

Answer (score 15):

`setup.py` is the file with the actual instructions how to build your software. These instructions might have some configuration options, e.g. for unit tests you might be able to indicate whether test coverage should be computed or not, or the install prefix etc.

`setup.cfg` is a file which might be used to specify such options in addition to reading the command line when calling `python setup.py <somecommand>`.

The [documentation for `setup.cfg`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/distutils/configfile.html) states:

> Often, it’s not possible to write down everything needed to build a
>   distribution a priori: you may need to get some information from the
>   user, or from the user’s system, in order to proceed. As long as that
>   information is fairly simple—a list of directories to search for C
>   header files or libraries, for example—then providing a configuration
>   file, setup.cfg, for users to edit is a cheap and easy way to solicit
>   it. Configuration files also let you provide default values for any
>   command option, which the installer can then override either on the
>   command-line or by editing the config file.

Answer (score 13):

`setup.py` is an integral part of a python package which includes details or information about the files that should be a package. This includes the required dependencies for installation and functioning of your Python package, entry points, license, etc.

`setup.cfg` on the other hand is more about the settings for any plug-ins or the type of distribution you wish to create. bdist/sdist and further classification of universal or core-python wheel. It can also be used to configure some meta-data of the `setup.py`.