# pip: Cannot perform editable system-wide install of "pyproject.toml" project

Tags: python, linux, pip, debian, setuptools

Consider the following minimal Python project with setuptools packaging and a "pyproject.toml" file (see [setuptools Build System Support](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/build_meta.html)):

```sh
> tree myproject
myproject
|-- myproject
|   `-- __init__.py
|-- pyproject.toml
|-- setup.cfg
`-- setup.py
```

"setup.py" is only a minimal dummy file to enable support for [editable installs](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#editable-installs), as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60885212/1792200):

```py
from setuptools import setup

if __name__ == '__main__':
    setup()
```

When performing an editable install (`pip install -e`) to a virtualenv, everything works as expected:

```sh
> ls venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages | grep myproject
myproject.egg-link

> cat venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/easy-install.pth 
/myproject

> python3
>>> import myproject
Hello world!
```

The same is true for a **non-editable** system-wide install:

```sh
> ls /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages | grep myproject
myproject
myproject-1.0.dist-info

> python3
>>> import myproject
Hello world!
```

For an **editable system-wide** install, however, pip succeeds but does not result in a usable module:

```sh
> ls /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages | grep myproject
(No output)

> python3
>>> import myproject
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myproject'
```

I'm aware that there were [some issues in the past](https://discuss.python.org/t/pip-19-1-and-installing-in-editable-mode-with-pyproject-toml/1553) with "pyproject.toml" and editable installs. However, these appear to be fixed since 2019.

I have a relatively recent Debian Bullseye system with pip 20.3.4 and setuptools 52.0.0.

There also is [PEP 660](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0660/), which has [not been implemented](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/2816) by setuptools yet. However, the dummy "setup.py" file (see above) should work around that limitation.

Answer (score 1):

This is a Debian-specific problem.

Having a "pyproject.toml" file (i.e. a [PEP 518](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0518/) package), [enables build isolation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#cmdoption-no-build-isolation) by default. On Debian, that results in editable installs ending up in "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages" instead of "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages":

```sh
> ls /usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages
easy-install.pth  myproject.egg-link

> cat /usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/easy-install.pth 
/myproject
```

However, "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages" is not part of the default [Debian Python module paths](https://salsa.debian.org/cpython-team/python3-defaults/-/blob/master/policy/interpreter.rst).

I reported this behavior as [Debian bug #1004149](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=1004149). Until it has been fixed, one can work around it by using `pip install --no-build-isolation -e`.